# Learning Rust by porting from C

Tags: c, rust

I'm trying to learn Rust by porting a project from C. The first data structure I've started with is a `Buffer` that holds a pointer to some data, its length, and an optional destructor function. You create a `Buffer` from an existing allocation, which the `Buffer` then takes ownership of, calling your provided destructor function when the `Buffer` is destroyed. For convenience, the C version also provided a function that would copy the data for you. I'm struggling with how this would map to Rust.

Here's a simplified excerpt of the C code (for brevity, I've removed error handling):

```
typedef void (*destruct_func)(void*);

typedef struct {
    void* data;
    size_t len;
    destruct_func destructor; /**< destructor for data ptr, or null */
} buffer_t;

buffer_t* buffer_new_direct (void* data, size_t length, destruct_func destructor)
{
    buffer_t* buf = malloc (sizeof (buffer_t));
    buf->data = data;
    buf->len = length;
    buf->destructor = destructor;
    return buf;
}

buffer_t* buffer_new_copy (void* data, size_t length)
{
    void* copy = malloc (length);
    return buffer_new_direct (memcpy (copy, data, length), length, &free);
}
```

And here's what I have so far in Rust:

```
pub struct Buffer<'a> {
    data: *mut u8,
    length: usize,
    destructor: Option<Box<Fn(*mut u8) + 'a>>
}

impl<'a> Buffer<'a> {
    pub fn new_direct<F: 'a>(data: *mut u8, length: usize, destructor: Option<F>) -> Buffer<'a>
        where F: Fn(*mut u8)
    {
        Buffer {
            data: data,
            length: length,
            destructor: destructor.map(|d| Box::new(d) as Box<Fn(*mut u8)>)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this idiomatic Rust? I still need to take existing allocations from C code, so I thought using a raw pointer for `data` would be best. However, I would also like to have a method that creates a `Buffer` from something like `&[u8]` so I can create them more easily from Rust code. How would I do that? What would the destructor be in that case? What would the Rust equivalent of `buffer_new_copy` be?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Look at the `From` trait for your question about building a `Buffer` from a `&[u8]`.

Comment: If you are looking for code review, you may be better off asking on [Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) or perhaps [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. This is not a request for a code review. I am trying to understand a new language based on a language I already know, and am asking some simple questions to clarify that understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your Rust code is more versatile than your C code: `Fn` can be a closure (ie, a function accompanied by some data). To represent a function pointer, you can use `fn` instead.

The problem of the `Fn` trait is that it is `!Sized` and therefore you need to `Box` it (which induces a memory allocation). Using `fn` directly is much more comfortable.

This lets us simplifying the current code greatly:

```
pub struct Buffer {
    data: *mut u8,
    length: usize,
    destructor: Option<fn(*mut u8)>,
}

impl Buffer {
    pub fn new_direct(data: *mut u8, length: usize, destructor: Option<fn(*mut u8)>) -> Buffer
    {
        Buffer {
            data: data,
            length: length,
            destructor: destructor
        }
    }
}
```

Though as noted by @Francis Gagné, this constructor will ultimately lead to potential unsafety (typical, when interacting with C) so would be better off marked `unsafe`.

I also wonder why the `destructor` is optional, Rust has a slice type (`&[T]`) which is generally used for non-owning; if you want to switch from owning to non-owning, the idiomatic way is to use [`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) as in `std::borrow::Cow<'a, NonOwning>`. You would need a dedicated slice type, of course.

Now, in order to actually call the destructor automatically, you implement `Drop`:

```
impl Drop for Buffer {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.destructor.map(|d| d(self.data));
    }
}
```

We can also implement conversion to a slice. This is done by implementing the `Deref` and `DerefMut` traits:

```
impl Deref for Buffer {
    type Target = [u8];

    fn deref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(self.data, self.length) }
    }
}

impl DerefMut for Buffer {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(self.data, self.length) }
    }
}
```

It gives us a lot of goodies (see what `Vec` [gains from it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#deref-methods)).

Finally, we can use the `libc` library to provide raw allocation and de-allocation, however it's currently unstable so you'll need a nightly compiler or to use the library from crates.io (I'll go the unstable road here):

```
#![feature(libc)]

impl Clone for Buffer {
    fn clone(&self) -> Buffer {
        fn destroy(data: *mut u8) {
            unsafe { libc::free(data as *mut _) }
        }

        let ptr = unsafe {
            let ptr = libc::malloc(self.length) as *mut _;
            std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(self.data, ptr, self.length);
            ptr
        };

        Buffer {
            data: ptr,
            length: self.length,
            destructor: Some(destroy),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I also wonder why the destructor is optional" - I suppose the trick is the `Buffer` can either own the data or not, depending on whether destructor is set. For instance, it could also be initialized with a pointer to some statically allocated data. I think this was the source of some of my confusion, since Rust seems so bifurcated between owned and unowned.

Answer (score 2):

It's as idiomatic as it can get... Like C++, Rust relies on [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for resource management, so one usually doesn't invoke a destructor manually, but since you're interoperating with C, you'll have to do it anyway.

`void*` would be best represented as `*mut ()` or `*mut libc::c_void` in Rust.

Your `Buffer` struct should have an implementation of [`Drop`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) that invokes the destructor, so that you never need to call it manually. However, the destructor is likely to be "unsafe", since it will need to cast the `data` pointer to something else, or call an unsafe FFI function (e.g. `libc::free`). Unfortunately, Rust's function traits cannot be used for `unsafe` functions, so you cannot encode that in the type system and the call to the destructor will appear to be safe, even though the destructor itself performs unsafe operations. What I'd do as a workaround is to mark `new_direct` as `unsafe`, since dropping a `Direct` might not be memory safe if `data` is invalidated before the destructor is run.